# How can I check if a product photo is "excluded"?

Tags: template, products

My product page template seems to be showing all photos linked to a product, even if they have the "Exclude" option set. How can I check if an image has the "exclude" option set? I want to add a simple "if not" statement to my template that says "if it is not excluded, display it."

UPDATE:

I tried the following code and it still showed all images

```
<?php $ac=0; foreach ($_product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image): ?>
                <?php if( $image->getExclude()==0 ): ?>
                <li id="navi1" onClick="changeClass1()" >
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="nav-image" name="prdImage">
        <img class="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image') ->init($_product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize();?>" src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image') ->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->resize(66,66);?>"  alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image') ->init($_product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize(1200);?>">
                </a>
               </li>
            <?php $ac++;
            endif;
              endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

magento media `attribute`  a have field  name `disabled` or `exclude` which tell which image are in `excluded list`

check:

```
    Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages() as $_image):
/* product image in exclude in list */
    if( $_image->getExclude()==1){
    $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(301);
    }
    endforeach;
```

For getting non exclude try `getDisabled()==0` because it save it on database as 0

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages() as $_image):

        if( $_image->getDisabled()==0){
        $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(301);
        }
        endforeach;
```

Comment: I tried something similar but it is still showing all photos, including the ones that have "exclude" checkmarked. Please see my code above and let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Excluded () means image in exclude list

Comment: =!instead of == .just ckd it..

Comment: I will see on tomorrow .. Gn8

Comment: any idea on this one Amit? thanks

Comment: i have edit code..if getExclude()  is not work then use getdisabled()..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $ac=0; foreach ($_product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image): ?>
    <?php if( $image['disabled']!=1): ?>
            <li id="navi1" onClick="changeClass1()" >
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="nav-image" name="prdImage">
                    <img class="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image') ->init($_product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize();?>" src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image') ->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->resize(66,66);?>"  alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image') ->init($_product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize(1200);?>">
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php $ac++;
    endif;
endforeach; ?>
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250647/get-only-excluded-product-images)